# Configuring HERE maps on CartoDB Builder (config/app_config.yml)

Tags: carto, documentation, here-maps

I'm installing the CartoDB platform on productive environment. I'm working on about 2 weeks with all tutorials I can find with Google, reading the repository documentation, and all stuff that can help me to finish this job.

I'm stuck to configurate HERE basemaps, I have the app_id and app_code. I'm try to configurate by file config/app_config.yml, but without successful.
I try basically everything I could find on the web but still can't show the option on CartoDB Builder.

Where can I find some documentation?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.